# Zend Framework: Set Cookie in Controller Action

Tags: php, cookies, controller, action

I have the following controller in ZF1 with a "logout" action:

```
class DefaultController extends Website_Controller_Action 
{
    //...

    public function logoutAction()
    {
        try {
            if ($this->user && $this->user instanceof \Transfer_User) {
                $userLogin = new User_Login();              

                //set cookie here

                $userLogin->logout($this->user);                
            }
            Messages::addSuccess($this->view->translate('success_logout'));
            $this->_redirect('/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_redirect('/');
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

The action checks if the user is logged in and then does a logout. Before the logout is executed I want to set a cookie with some specific data that is read on the next login.

I tried `setcookie(...)` and `new Zend_Http_Cookie(...)` but both of them don't work. Is there any other way to set a cookie on a controller action in ZF1?

Thank you for your answers ;-)

Comment: Are you echoing something before setting cookie?

Comment: no, as far as I can see I'm not echoing anything. But maybe I miss something...